# error on moving Line object in crystal report programatically

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

```
strNAme = ds.Tables("report").Rows(i).Item("LabelName")
Dim Line As LineObject = DirectCast(rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects(strNAme), LineObject)

Line.Left = ds.Tables("report").Rows(i).Item("Align_Left")' ERROR IS HERE
Line.Top = ds.Tables("report").Rows(i).Item("Align_Top")

Line.Right = ds.Tables("report").Rows(i).Item("Align_Right")
Line.Bottom = ds.Tables("report").Rows(i).Item("Align_Bottom")
```

I am getting error on Line.Left :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
>
> **ErrorCode**=-2147213284
>
> Message="The line object's coordinates are not valid. Only vertical or
>   horizontal lines are supported."